# Active Admin Tag Collection with joined table

Tags: ruby, tags, foreign-keys, activeadmin

I have a problem to display the correct values in the Active Admin Tag collection.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuusN.png)

To build many to many relationships I created a joined table:

```
  create_table "profession_allocations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "master_id"
    t.integer "slave_id"
    t.index ["master_id"], name: "index_profession_allocations_on_master_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["slave_id"], name: "index_profession_allocations_on_slave_id", using: :btree
  end
```

and a model:

```
class ProfessionAllocation < ApplicationRecord

  has_and_belongs_to_many :master, :class_name => 'Profession'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :slave, :class_name => 'Profession'

end
```

to build relationships with my profession table:

```
create_table "professions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "kind",                                   null: false
    t.string   "list",                                   null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
    t.string   "summary_de", default: "summary german",  null: false
    t.string   "summary_en", default: "summary english", null: false
  end
```

and the model:

```
class Profession < ApplicationRecord

  validates_presence_of :kind, :list
  validates  :kind, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates  :list, presence: true
  validates  :summary_de, presence: true
  validates  :summary_en, presence: true

  has_many :master_profession_allocations, :class_name => 'ProfessionAllocation', :foreign_key => 'master_id'
  has_many :slave_profession_allocations, :class_name => 'ProfessionAllocation', :foreign_key => 'slave_id'

end
```

Inside Active Admin I use the gem *activeadmin_addons* to use tags, but I guess this does not madder for this issue.

```
    if f.object&.persisted?
          f.input :master_profession_allocations, as: :tags, collection: Profession.where.not(id: f.object.id).order('summary_en ASC'), display_name: :summary_en
        else
          f.input :master_profession_allocations, as: :tags, collection: Profession.all.order('summary_en ASC'), display_name: :summary_en
        end
end
```

While creating the ProfessionAllocation works fine with the Tag collection, the edit view makes problems, because it displays the ProfessionAllocations and not the related Professions.
My question is, how can I display the related Profession in the Tag Collection?

Best
Alex

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by create a subsection. This allows me also to store addtional data in the allocation:

```
f.inputs do
        f.has_many :master_profession_allocations, heading: 'Slaves', allow_destroy: true, new_record: true do |pa|
          if f.object&.persisted?
            pa.input :level, as: :select, collection: ProfessionAllocation::LEVELS
            pa.input :slave_id, as: :select, collection: Profession.joins('LEFT JOIN profession_allocations pa on professions.id = pa.master_id WHERE professions.id !='  + f.object.id.to_s).map { |pa| [pa.summary_en, pa.id] }
          else
            pa.input :level, as: :select, collection: ProfessionAllocation::LEVELS
            pa.input :slave_id, as: :select, collection: Profession.joins('LEFT JOIN profession_allocations pa on professions.id = pa.master_id').map { |pa| [pa.summary_en, pa.id] }
          end
        end
      end
```